# Check to see if a word contains certain letters?

Tags: android, words

I'm trying to make a program that will generate three random letters. Then the user will have to type a word that contains those letters, and is a valid word contained within the dictionary. But the issue I'm having is that I'm not sure how I would go about checking to see if the word that the user enters contains the three letters that were randomly generated. Then checking it against a dictionary part is simple.

Answer (score 1):

```
if(userStr.contains("rl1") && userStr.contains("rl2") && userStr.contains("rl3")) { 
    //user string contains random letter
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do use the `indexOf(char)` to find if the word contains the letter.

> If the char is present in string, it returns the index(>=0). If not, it
>   returns -1. So, a non-negative return value means that the char is present
>   in the word.

```
   Random r = new Random();
    char c1 = (char) (r.nextInt(26) + 'a');
    char c2 = (char) (r.nextInt(26) + 'a');
    char c3 = (char) (r.nextInt(26) + 'a');

    String word = "example";

    if(word.toLowerCase().indexOf(c1) >= 0 && word.toLowerCase().indexOf(c2) >= 0 && word.toLowerCase().indexOf(c3) >= 0)
        System.out.println("true");
    else
        System.out.println("try again");
```